# R Side by Side Histograms

Tags: r, vector, statistics, histogram

So I have a problem where I had to generate two random samples, and I am trying to display side-by-side histograms using par(), but I am having trouble making it work. Code is below:

```
set.seed(123) 
x <- rnorm(1000, 0, 2)

set.seed(123)
y <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)

cbind(x,y)

sd1 <- sd(x)
sd2 <- sd(y)

hist(x) 
hist(y)

par(mfrow = c(2,1)

xlim=c(-6,6)
```

- Also, how do I make x and y different colors on the histogram? Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the par(mfrow = c(2,1) should be par(mfrow = c(2,1))

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(1000, 0, 2)
set.seed(123)
y <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
cbind(x,y)
sd1 <- sd(x)
sd2 <- sd(y)
hist(x, col =c('red'))
hist(y, col =c('green'))
par(mfrow = c(2,1))    
xlim=c(-6,6)
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer. This sequence of commands does not generate the desired result. Moreover, if you would correct the sequence of suggested code, the histograms would be on top of each other and not side by side.